# Raspberry Pi CM4 with buildroot not loading Wi-Fi wlan0 interface

Tags: networking, wifi, buildroot, u-boot, compute-module-4

I am running a custom buildroot + uboot software with a 5.15.78-v8 linux kernel for a Raspberry Pi CM4 and am finding that the Wi-Fi driver by default isn't being loaded.

In dmesg, I am seeing these errors that look related to the driver not being loaded:

```
[21.2122] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-compute-module.bin failed with error -2
[21.2123] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[21.2124] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

`modinfo` also shows no usage of the brcmfmac module. and `ifconfig -a` doesn't show the wlan0 interface.

Does anyone know why my driver may not be loading correctly and timing out instead? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The trick with this is that one error message is meant to exist, and one isn't.

Comparing the above dmesg to the dmesg of a stock os pi, we see that `Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-compute-module.bin failed with error -2` is there when it's working. So, we only have to resolve the second issue with `brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt`.

My buildroot package was bringing in wifi drivers but not the right ones. The solution was to change the defconfig like so:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_BRCMFMAC_SDIO_FIRMWARE_RPI=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_BRCMFMAC_SDIO_FIRMWARE_RPI_BT is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_BRCMFMAC_SDIO_FIRMWARE_RPI_WIFI=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_BRCM_BCM43XXX is not set
```

This brings in the right libraries from this repo which worked for me: https://github.com/LibreELEC/brcmfmac_sdio-firmware-rpi/tree/master/firmware/brcm